# Stimulsoft report right-to-left

Tags: reporting, right-to-left, direction, persian, stimulsoft

I have a website that calculate the cost of something and I use Stimulsoft report to create a simple factor form for my customers and also I use Persian letters, English letters and numbers together in my factor form (for ex: [MyProblem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kQx6g.png)) and set the page direction in my website to right-to-left(because of my language is Persian), but when I click on the create report in my website and website pass the parameters to the report and create it, they destroy the arrangement. It seems like that right-to-left doesn't work.

**Summery:** In the stimulsoft designer we can just design in left-to-light state and when we run it into a website with right-to-left state it destroy the arrangement of elements, numbers, letters and etc.

[In my Designer everything is OK](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bhJ7M.png)

[But in the browser with right-to-left attribute, it destroy the arrangement](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gRf7o.png)

Thanks.

Answer (score 7):

Right click on the Properties and select Professional item , then in the Text Option -> Right To Left set to true

Answer (score 3):

Please tries to set the direction of your HTML 'div' element as 'ltr' always.

Comment: This is the only correct asnwer!

Answer (score 1):

[image: view image steps]

Properties -> text Options -> Right to left set True